# How to pass type for Link from next/link in Nextjs

Tags: typescript, next.js

I am still new in typescript, and i can't really figure it out how can i pass the type into the parameter for a custom function since i refactor it, an simplified example in code below :

utility.ts

```
export function getLinkAndProps (route: string, nextLink: ??) {  //I try to pass LinkProps from next/link 
    const Link = (route === "/works" || route === "/books") ? nextLink : "a"
    const linkProps = Link === "a" ? {rel:"noopener noreferrer", target: "_blank"} : {scroll: false};
    return {
        Link,
        linkProps
    }
}
```

A linkWrapper in Navbar.ts

```
import NextLink from "next/link";
import { getLinkAndProps } from "@/utils/utility";
//...
const LinkItem = ({ children, href, path }: LinkItemProps) => {
    const active = path === href;
    const { Link, linkProps } = getLinkAndProps(href, NextLink) //typescript will complain here for NextLink saying Property 'href' is missing in type  

    return (
        <Link href={href} {...linkProps}>
            {children}
        </Link>
    );
}
```

Well if i pass in "any" type in the parameter it will work, but i want to figure it out how can i pass the right type ?

**Update**: after I inspect in Nextjs Link source code If i tried like this it work but...

```
import { LinkProps } from "next/link";

type TestProps = React.ForwardRefExoticComponent<Omit<React.AnchorHTMLAttributes<HTMLAnchorElement>, keyof LinkProps> & LinkProps & {
    children?: React.ReactNode;
} & React.RefAttributes<HTMLAnchorElement>>;
```

there should be a way to do this without copy/paste all this code ?

**Update2**: oh well since the second parameter won't changed I just remove the parameter and import directly on my function and use it, it should be ok :>

Comment: Have you tried the `NextComponentType<LinkProps>` ? You will also need to use these 2 import: `import { NextComponentType } from 'next/types'` and `import { LinkProps } from 'next/link'`

Comment: @Atzuki I test it unfortunaly it didn't work :/